# How to pass dynamically updated value from one component to another in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a React newbie, came across an interesting challenge to create "fake ecommerce page" with [this api](https://api.escuelajs.co/api/v1/products).

My `Products.js` file is this. I get api response and save it to a state(console logging it in one line to make sure it's working). You click on a SVG icon of `+` sign and that item gets "added" to the cart(don't want to add whole item for now, but just make it seems like it's adding it with `setCartItems(cartItems + 1)` so only number increases). Only thing is that the `cart` icon is in `Header.js` component, and I need to pass it there somehow. I've tried with props but couldn't get it to work.

Any help is very much appreciated since I want to learn from your code.

```html
import React from 'react'
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import plus from '../images/plus.svg'

export default function Products(props) {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([])
    const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState(0)

    const updateCart = () => {
        setCartItems(cartItems + 1)
        console.log(cartItems)
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        axios({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://api.escuelajs.co/api/v1/products'
        }).then((response) => {
            setProducts(response.data)
            console.log(response.data)
        })
    }, [])

    return (
        <section className="bg-white py-8">
            <div className="container mx-auto flex items-center flex-wrap pt-4 pb-12">
                <nav id="store" className="w-full z-30 top-0 px-6 py-1">
                    <div
                        className="w-full container mx-auto flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between mt-0 px-2 py-3">
                        <a className="uppercase tracking-wide no-underline hover:no-underline font-bold text-gray-800 text-xl "
                           href="#">
                            Store
                        </a>
                        <div className="flex items-center" id="store-nav-content">
                            <a className="pl-3 inline-block no-underline hover:text-black" href="#">
                                <svg className="fill-current hover:text-black" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                     width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                    <path d="M7 11H17V13H7zM4 7H20V9H4zM10 15H14V17H10z"></path>
                                </svg>
                            </a>
                            <a className="pl-3 inline-block no-underline hover:text-black" href="#">
                                <svg className="fill-current hover:text-black" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                     width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                    <path
                                        d="M10,18c1.846,0,3.543-0.635,4.897-1.688l4.396,4.396l1.414-1.414l-4.396-4.396C17.365,13.543,18,11.846,18,10 c0-4.411-3.589-8-8-8s-8,3.589-8,8S5.589,18,10,18z M10,4c3.309,0,6,2.691,6,6s-2.691,6-6,6s-6-2.691-6-6S6.691,4,10,4z"></path>
                                </svg>
                            </a>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
                {
                    products.slice(0, 20).map((product) => {
                            return (
                                <div className="w-full md:w-1/3 xl:w-1/4 p-6 flex flex-col" key={product.id}>
                                    <div>
                                        <img className="hover:grow hover:shadow-lg" src={product.category.image}
                                             alt={product.description}/>
                                        <div className="pt-3 flex items-center justify-between">
                                            <p className="uppercase font-bold text-lg">{product.title}</p>
                                            <img src={plus} width='20px' onClick={updateCart} alt={product.description}/>
                                        </div>
                                        <p className="pt-1 text-left text-gray-900">{product.price} €</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            )
                        }
                    )
                }
            </div>
        </section>
    )
}
```

This is my `Header.js` file.

```html
import React from 'react'

export default function Header() {
    return (
        <nav id="header" className="w-full z-30 top-0 py-1">
            <div className="w-full container mx-auto flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between mt-0 px-6 py-3">

                <label className="cursor-pointer md:hidden block">
                    <svg className="fill-current text-gray-900" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="34" height="34" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                        <title>menu</title>
                        <path d="M0 3h20v2H0V3zm0 6h20v2H0V9zm0 6h20v2H0v-2z"></path>
                    </svg>
                </label>
                <input className="hidden" type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle" />

                <div className="hidden md:flex md:items-center md:w-auto w-full order-3 md:order-1" id="menu">
                    <nav>
                        <ul className="md:flex items-center justify-between text-base text-gray-700 pt-4 md:pt-0">
                            <li><a className="inline-block no-underline hover:text-black hover:underline py-2 px-4" href="#">Shop</a></li>
                            <li><a className="inline-block no-underline hover:text-black hover:underline py-2 px-4" href="#">About</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>

                <div className="order-1 md:order-2">
                    <a className="flex items-center tracking-wide no-underline hover:no-underline font-bold text-gray-800 text-xl " href="#">
                        <svg className="fill-current text-gray-800 mr-2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="34" height="34" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                            <path d="M5,22h14c1.103,0,2-0.897,2-2V9c0-0.553-0.447-1-1-1h-3V7c0-2.757-2.243-5-5-5S7,4.243,7,7v1H4C3.447,8,3,8.447,3,9v11 C3,21.103,3.897,22,5,22z M9,7c0-1.654,1.346-3,3-3s3,1.346,3,3v1H9V7z M5,10h2v2h2v-2h6v2h2v-2h2l0.002,10H5V10z"></path>
                        </svg>
                        NORDICS
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div className="order-2 md:order-3 flex items-center" id="nav-content">

                    <a className="inline-block no-underline hover:text-black" href="#">
                        <svg className="fill-current hover:text-black" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="34" height="34" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                            <circle fill="none" cx="12" cy="7" r="3"></circle>
                            <path d="M12 2C9.243 2 7 4.243 7 7s2.243 5 5 5 5-2.243 5-5S14.757 2 12 2zM12 10c-1.654 0-3-1.346-3-3s1.346-3 3-3 3 1.346 3 3S13.654 10 12 10zM21 21v-1c0-3.859-3.141-7-7-7h-4c-3.86 0-7 3.141-7 7v1h2v-1c0-2.757 2.243-5 5-5h4c2.757 0 5 2.243 5 5v1H21z"></path>
                        </svg>
                    </a>

                    <a className="pl-3 inline-block no-underline hover:text-black" href="#">
                        <svg className="fill-current hover:text-black" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="34" height="34" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                            <path d="M21,7H7.462L5.91,3.586C5.748,3.229,5.392,3,5,3H2v2h2.356L9.09,15.414C9.252,15.771,9.608,16,10,16h8 c0.4,0,0.762-0.238,0.919-0.606l3-7c0.133-0.309,0.101-0.663-0.084-0.944C21.649,7.169,21.336,7,21,7z M17.341,14h-6.697L8.371,9 h11.112L17.341,14z"></path>
                            <circle cx="10.5" cy="18.5" r="1.5"></circle>
                            <circle cx="17.5" cy="18.5" r="1.5"></circle>
                        </svg>
                       
                        <div className="inline-flex absolute top-4 justify-center items-center w-5 h-5 text-xs font-bold text-white bg-red-500 rounded-full">NUMBER OF ITEMS IN CART GOES HERE</div>
                    </a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    )
}
```

And finally, if needed, this is my `App.js` file.

```html
import './App.css';

import About from './components/About';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Hero from './components/Hero';
import Products from './components/Products';

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <Hero />
      <Products />
      <About />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I provide two methods for your refrence:

1.**By using props**:
just put your state and set function at their father element, in your situation you can put in App.js, then props to any components you want:

```
App.js
```

```js
import './App.css';

import About from './components/About';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Hero from './components/Hero';
import Products from './components/Products';
import axios from 'axios'

function App() {
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]) // put here
const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState(0)  // put here
// get your api here
useEffect(() => {
    axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.escuelajs.co/api/v1/products'
    }).then((response) => {
        setProducts(response.data)
    })
}, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header setCartItems={setCartItems} cartItems={cartItems}/>
      <Hero />
      <Products cartItems={cartItems} setCartItems={setCartItems} products={products} setProducts={setProducts}/>
      <About />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

after then in your Products.js and Header.js can get props data, and can get props set feunction to update state.

But I think put global state is better,
I recommend useContext or zustand to do it!

2.**Put in zustand**:
create file named store.js, then npm install zustand

```
store.js
```

```js
import create from 'zustand';
// this is our useStore hook that we can use in our components to get parts of the store and call actions
const useStore = create((set, get) => ({
    cartItems: 0,
    setCartItems: (value) =>
        set((state) => ({
            cartItems: value,
        })),
}));

export default useStore;
```

`Product.js and Header.js` add below code:

```js
import useStore from './store'; // import the store you writed before

export default function Products(props) {
     // get your store state and function
     const { cartItems, setCartItems } = useStore();

     // update your store state
     const updateCart = () => {
        setCartItems(cartItems + 1)
    }
     const minusCart = () => {
        setCartItems(cartItems - 1)
    }
    
    //...your other code
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You either need to use global state management like redux or pass a callback function from the header to the products component to update the state. React is unidirectional data flow downward, so you can't pass props back up like you can from parent to child.